# Android 9-patch drawable not showing only in some versions

Tags: android, drawable, nine-patch

I've a very strange problem with a specific `9-patches` drawable, only on some devices (works on `emulators`): it simply does not show. I've tried everything. Renaming the file does not work. Removing the **.9** part from the name of the file shows the `drawable`. Using other `9-patches` it works.

The files are `expander_close_holo_light.9.png` and `expander_open_holo_light.9.png` from latest sdk.

The image is set in an ImageView with setImageResource. The style of the view has a background Drawable, that becomes blue when touched.
So I know the view is correctly layouted, because touch works even when the image is not shown. I think the problem lies only on the image itself (as I said other 9-patches drawables work).

Any clue?

Thank you,
Ignazio

Comment: paste some code here, what you have tried

Comment: Be more specific. How exactly are you using the 9-patch?

Comment: I was using in an ImageView in resource xml, responding to touch. I solved changing the files a little bit. Seems like a bug of some non-Google Android versions.